# How to understand IR checksum

Tags: reverse-engineering, checksum, infrared

I'm trying to understand how crc is calculated of below data packets of unbranded air con remote controller. it's last 4 bits seem to be crc and data packet is 8 bytes long. I can understand how to extract the data packet but not crc. First 3 bits are fixed.

data pattern eg  1)  0010 0100 0100 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1110 
data pattern eg  2)  0010 1000 0101 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1101 
data pattern eg  3)  0010 1000 0110 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 
data pattern eg  4)  0010 1000 0111 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1011 
data pattern eg  5)  0010 1000 1000 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010 
data pattern eg  6)  0010 1000 1001 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1001 
data pattern eg  7)  0010 1000 1010 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 
data pattern eg  8)  0010 1000 1011 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 
data pattern eg  9)  0010 1000 0000 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 
data pattern eg 10)  0010 1000 0001 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 
data pattern eg 11)  0010 1000 0010 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
data pattern eg 12)  0010 1000 0011 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aprn4.png)

Comment: How did you find out last 4 bits are crc? That same resource might also contain the details of crc calculation. Do you know what other bits mean? Which protocol is being used? Any references to look at, so we're not just guessing?

Comment: thank for replying me:) first 3 bits are not changing, other bits contains timer, fan speed, temperature and other parameters. i can understand up to 40th bit,  next four bits are not. without last four bits air conditioner does not answer. its protocol is NEC.

Comment: i have added sample image as well.

Comment: Where is all your protocol info coming from? Does it also say anything about last four bits?

Comment: not getting from some where...i just compared and analyzed. but all calculations are correct except last four bits.

Comment: Ah, so you are trying to reverse engineer this then? Unless you're lucky and find someone doing exactly this, you'll need way more samples to analyse. Currenty just XOR-ing all nibbles leads to result 0001 on all samples - which may or may not match other samples.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me....i tried many ways, but could't get success..:/

Comment: Can you get 10+ different samples and include them in your post? Maybe someone here notices a pattern.

Comment: it is in "sample image" link, below my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be just an inverted sum.

Adding up all but last 4 bits, and then `((x&1111)^1111)`:

```
0010 + 0100 + 0100 + 0011 =  1101  ->  0010*
0010 + 1000 + 0101 + 0011 = 10010  ->  1101
0010 + 1000 + 0110 + 0011 = 10011  ->  1100
0010 + 1000 + 0111 + 0011 = 10100  ->  1011
0010 + 1000 + 1000 + 0011 = 10101  ->  1010
0010 + 1000 + 1001 + 0011 = 10110  ->  1001
0010 + 1000 + 1010 + 0011 = 10111  ->  1000
0010 + 1000 + 1011 + 0011 = 11000  ->  0111
0010 + 1000 + 0000 + 0011 =  1101  ->  0010
0010 + 1000 + 0001 + 0011 =  1110  ->  0001
0010 + 1000 + 0010 + 0011 =  1111  ->  0000
0010 + 1000 + 0011 + 0011 = 10000  ->  1111
```

Note that first sample is incorrect (should be 1110), but the rest match. I'm not sure if that's an error in my algorithm, or error in input data (looking at the photo, I don't see where 0010 0100 appears).

Also note that samples provided are very similar (only bits 8,9,10,11 differ, if we exclude first sample), so there are probably many ways to end up with "a solution".

Comment: Yesss.......that is the correct way. it works with other samples as well. Thank you very much for spending your valuable time for me.:)